# Unable to propose migration other than to meta.mechanics.SE

Tags: discussion, bug

I flagged [this question](https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/questions/35243/fast-linear-actuator) as belonging on another SE site ([robotics](http://robotics.stackexchange.com)), but the only option I was given for where to put the question was here on Meta. Shouldn't there be a way to select the site I think it should go to?

Answer (score 5):

This is as designed. Only mods can move things to other sites besides Meta.

Comment: What's the right way to flag such posts? To meta, or use some other flag?

Comment: @dlu, you could also mention me or Larry in the chat and bring the question to our attention.